# Could not resolve to a type in "XWPFDocument doc=new XWPFDocument(inputStream) "

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to convert/generate PDF document from .docx which is from my application as a UploadedFile object.

Here are the JARS used as part of iText and POI.

- com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7 (allowed to use only 2.1.7)
- poi:3.12,poi-ooxml:3.12
- poi-ooxml-schemas:3.12
- poi-scratchpad:3.12
- xmlbeans:2.3.0

[image]

Note: When I manually take a file from desktop and pass it as an inputstream to XWPFDocument, it works.

Comment: Show code. the class name is `XWPFDocument`. This is case sensitive. Your title shows the case incorrectly, that could be a typo, but I can't help you unless you show code.

Comment: What exact error occurs? Complete stack trace please! And how is `Inputstream filecontent` created? [UploadedFile.getInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17824_01/dsc_docs/docs/jscreator/apis/webui/com/sun/rave/web/ui/model/UploadedFile.html#getInputStream%28%29)? If so, where is the `UploadedFile` coming from? And **please** don't post code as picture. Code is text.  And there is a special formatting possible for code in this site's question editor.

Comment: @AxelRichter Is there a way i can chat you with?I am not able to type in more.I am a newbie to stackoverflow on posting questions.bear with me please

Comment: @jmarkmurphy the title has been modified.